# Using FontAwesome icon in download button next to "Download" text

Tags: html, css, button, font-awesome

I am looking to try and accomplish this look for my download button:

[this http://instasermon.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screen-Shot-2016-12-18-at-8.18.12-PM.png](http://instasermon.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screen-Shot-2016-12-18-at-8.18.12-PM.png)

I am using this code for my download button

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="download" value=" download"/>
```

But need to add the FontAwesome download icon to the left of the "Download" text inside the download button

```
fa-download
```

Above is the FontAwesome icon code.

I found a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/19/) on another post that was similar to what I am looking for, except when I try to insert my fa-download code front FontAwesome, it doesn't work

Comment: try using button instead, like so : https://jsfiddle.net/uv8ej0nb/2/

Answer (score 0):

The external resources you are using are causing the problem. you might be using http in front of it instead of https

remove two cdn you were using for font-awesome.css and bootstrap.no-icons.min.csss and try these two cdn

https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Secondly use the fa-icons inside a  tag. it's more flexible for applying css on them : like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
```

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/29/). and here's a working snippet

```js
var radio_x86 = document.getElementById('x86');
var radio_x64 = document.getElementById('x64');

var button = document.getElementById('download');

button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    if(radio_x86.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar500.exe");
    }else if(radio_x64.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-500.exe");
    } else {
        alert("Please check one of the options first.");
    }
}
```

```css
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before,
input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-right: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: "\f10c"; /* circle-blank */
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* circle */
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* check-empty */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f058"; /* check */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="x86">
  <input type="radio" name="download" id="x86" />
  <span>winrar x86</span>
</label>

<label for="x64">
  <input type="radio" name="download" id="x64" />
  <span>winrar x64</span>
</label>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Download</span></button>
```

Add the span or you'll run into trouble styling the thing.
Also, I'm not sure if the answer by the fist person is how it's done in Bootstrap land, but Bootstrap is reviled in the accessibility community for good reasons. DO NOT remove the aria-hidden or you'll be reading nonsensical gibberish to screenreader users. This is explained very well on the Font Awesome website.

Good luck, and have fun.